# VisualStudio Shim does't work on different thread

Tags: microsoft-fakes

I have a unit test that test a threaded code.
I am shiming one of methods being called in a different thread but when the test is executed, the production code is executed instead of my fake method.
I've tested that if i run the code in the same thread as the unit test, my fake method is called.
Is this known limitation?
Thanks

Comment: I logged a bug on this today at microsoft connect. I can't find anything on the internet about shims not working in a multi threading enviroment.

Comment: can i get url? i believe there is a way to vote a bug in connect

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806872/shims-does-not-working-with-a-threadpool-queueuserworkitem

Answer (score 2):

OK it turns out ShimsContext was disposed before my threaded method was called.
VS fake is global meaning it applies to all threads.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding a longer sleep fixes the problem, as you say the ShimsContext was disposed when the shim it self whould have been called:

```
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            bool shimcalled = false;
            ShimClass1 h = new ShimClass1();
            ShimClass1.MyStaticMethodToBeShimed = () =>
            {
                shimcalled = true;
            };


            new Class1().MyMethodUnderTest();

            Thread.Sleep(1000); //or wait with a while loop till shimcalled = true: 
            //int couter = 0; while (counter < 100 && shimcalled == false) { counter++; Thread.Sleep(10);}

            Assert.IsTrue(shimcalled);
        }
```